# sklearn roc_auc_score multiclass ovo average error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The sklearn 1.1.2 doc says for function `roc_auc_score`

> average=None is only implemented for multi_class='ovo'

However, when I try to run

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y_pred = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y_pred_proba = [
    [0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7],
]

roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_proba, multi_class="ovo", average=None)
```

I got the following Error:

```
NotImplementedError: average=None is not implemented for multi_class='ovo'
```

This is a bug? Can't find any mention of this issue anywhere.

I am using sklearn verison 1.1.2:

```
>>> sklearn.__version__
'1.1.2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just typo, not a bug. It can be seen in code for [`_multiclass_roc_auc_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb24/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L588)(which is called in `roc_auc_score` function in case of multiple classes) and from meaning of `average` parameter. So `average == None` should return whatever was computed, and for `ovo` case it's matrix, which kind of doesn't match with purpose of this roc-auc function: return either one value (as in case with `average=macro`) or return value for each class (`multi_class=ovr` and `average=None`).

By the way, `ovo`-case matrix still may be gained by adopting [`_average_multiclass_ovo_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/metrics/_base.py#L132) function with one change -- insted of `return np.average(pair_scores)` should be `return pair_scores`.